# JavaScript Constructor - How Does JavaScript Determine the Constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm currently learning everything I can about OOP with JavaScript, and I've got the following code:

```
var Person = (function() {
    var protectedMembers;

    function capitalizeString(str) {
        return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }

    function PersonConstructor(name, surname, protected) {
        protectedMembers = protected || {};

        protectedMembers.capitalizeString = capitalizeString;
        this.name = capitalizeString(name);
        this.surname = capitalizeString(surname);
    }

    return PersonConstructor;

}());
```

So how does JavaScript know that PersonContructor is the constructor, and it's not capitalizeString?  I mean, I know that I mean for the function PersonConstructor to be the constructor, but how does the JavaScript engine or whatever determine that?  Is it only because I'm returning it?  Or is it because I'm using "this" in PersonConstructor?  Or is it due to both things?

I did look at other StackOverflow questions which talk about JavaScript and constructors, but they didn't answer this specific question unless I missed something.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a constructor if you call it with `new`.

Comment: If you could easily access `capitalizeString` from outside the IIFE, you could do `new capitalizeString("")` and it would still "work" - then you would have used `capitalizeString` as a constructor. Of course you wouldn't do that because it doesn't make sense (the function is not initialising any properties), but JS doesn't stop you from doing it (it would if you had used `class` syntax with methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how does JavaScript know that PersonContructor is the constructor, and it's not capitalizeString?
>
> Is it only because I'm returning it?

Because you are returning `PersonContructor`, `PersonContructor` is assigned to `Person`. You aren't returning `capitalizeString`, so it isn't assigned to `Person`.

If you were to later call `new Person()` it would know it is a constructor because you used the `new` keyword.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I was a little puzzled over this!